# Correct way to save and load Sklearn's CalibratedClassifierCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, calibration

I am coming across different predictions when I load my CalibratedClassiferCV and run predic_proba compared to when I initially fit the model and run predict_proba. Any idea as to why this might be? The data and the model parameters are the same, but the predictions are vastly different. Below is my code using pickle, but I have tried with joblib as well with same results.

The following works fine:

```
#Train and fit model
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_estimators=1800, max_features='auto', max_depth=100, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, bootstrap=False)
cccv=CalibratedClassifierCV(clf,method='sigmoid',cv=5)
cccv.fit(X_train, y_train)
#save model
filename='TESTwCV_04272020.sav'
pickle.dump(cccv,open(filename,'wb'))
#load model and make predictions from loaded model
model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
cccv_final_probs=model.predict_proba(X_final)[:,1]
cccv_final_pred=model.predict(X_final)
```

But if I were to start fresh (i.e., clear variables), load the model and make predictions, my output is way different from the output above:

```
filename='TESTwCV_04272020.sav'
model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
cccv_final_probs=model.predict_proba(X_final)[:,1]
cccv_final_pred=model.predict(X_final)
```

As Ive said, the first set of code works fine, but I am creating a ML pipeline and I don't want to have to train a new model every time I get new data  as I want to limit time to process and I want to evaluate the performance of the same model overtime (this is critical). Any insights would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mistake was that the order of my factors in my data was different in the training model versus when I would run new data from the loaded model. Newbie mistake I figured I would keep this up here in case someone else ran into a similar issue.